# How to get AM/PM from TimePickerAndroid in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using `TimePickerAndroid` of React Native and using 12hours timing,

So, it is working fine and shows AM/PM to select and picker returned me hours and minutes, but I did not found anyway to get that `AM` is selected or `PM`, code is below.

```
async showTimePicker() {
    const { action, minute, hour } = await TimePickerAndroid.open({
        is24Hour: false,
    });
    if (action === TimePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
        return;
    }
    const selectedTime = `${hour}:${minute}`;
    this.setState({ selectedTime })
}
```

I just need to know that `AM` is selected or `PM` everything else is working fine.

[official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timepickerandroid) for reference.

Thank you.

Comment: As I think it showing only the time hour (0-23), minute (0-59), no AM/PM. If you really need to show you can use a trick (like if hour>=12 --> PM )

Comment: @DinithMinura Unfortunately you think right, but my target is normal users so i cannot show them 24 hours clock to use your trick but, anyway I don't understand how can they allow to use 12 hours clock and let users select am/pm but did not returned am/pm value?

Comment: I add an answer with a sample code segment, you can try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition to display AM/PM, here I added an example code segment for you. Sriraman's answer also explained to use this kind of method.

```
async showTimePicker() {

var { action, minute, hour } = await TimePickerAndroid.open({      
  is24Hour: false,
});


if (action === TimePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
    return;
}
// setting AM/PM and hour to 12 by checking condition
let am_pm = 'AM';

if(hour>11){
  am_pm = 'PM';
  if(hour>12){
    hour = hour - 12;
  }
}

if(hour == 0){
  hour = 12;
}
  const selectedTime = `${hour}:${minute} ${am_pm}` ;
  this.setState({ selectedTime })
}
```

Comment: in which case did you thought that an hour can become `0` ?

Comment: once user select 12:00 to 12:59 AM from the time picker

Answer (score 2):

Flag is just for showing to the user inside the timer popup. Once user selects the time, It will give you 24 hour format only.. If user select "2:00 PM", the return value will be 14 hours and 00 minutes. while displaying in any other place, You can just convert into AM/PM and display it.

Expect only 24 hours format from the `TimePickerAndroid`.

Comment: oh thanks for the info, well Its weird to showing `12hours` and returning `24hours` and then they says they are making developers life easy with libraries. :D

Answer (score 0):

Whatever *bool* value you set for is24Hour, the time picker returns hours in the 24 hour format. That is, if you select 8:00 PM, the time picker returns the JSON Object `{action:'timeSetAction', hour:20, minute:0}`.
You're right that the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timepickerandroid) doesn't show this.